# C Macro Expression Return Value

Tags: c, macros, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I am writing a devices handler for my embedded systems class and I am trying to use a macro to check if the ith bit is set. My macro doesn't seem to work correctly but the inline function does. Why is that?

```
#define TEST0 i&0x01
#define CLEAR0 i &= 0x01


inline short test0(short i) {
    return i&0x01;
}


int main() {
    short flag = 1;

    //this doesnt work
    if (TEST0(flag) == 0x01) {
        CLEAR0(flag);
    }

    //but this does
    if (test0(flag) == 0x01) {
        CLEAR0(flag);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is the argument in TEST0 definition?

Comment: @user2014258 I rolled back to the previous version because your edit made it impossible to see what was the problem in the first place leaving the question not useful for later readers.

Comment: Do you really need that macros? After some programming experience, meaning of `x & 1<<n` and `x &= ~(1<<n)` inline would be clear as a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error. The macro needs an argument.

```
#define TEST0(i) ((i) & 0x01)
```

Also, use whitespace for readability and parentheses for security.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to operator precedence problems. Also, you need a parameter to your macro.

It's being parsed like this:

```
if (i & (0x01 == 0x01))
```

Add parens and a parameter to fix:

```
#define TEST0(i) ((i)&0x01)
#define CLEAR0(i) ((i) &= 0x01)
```

Comment: There's a syntax error too. `i` is undeclared where it's used (after macro expansion), since it's not part of the argument list of the macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass an argument to your macro, it should be defined to accept an argument:

```
#define TEST0(i) ((i)&0x01)
#define CLEAR0(i) do { i&=0x01; } while(0)
```

(other modifications deal with precedence and syntax).